# Troubleshooting "no internet" on D-Link DSL-2750B

Tags: networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, dsl

On my home network I am running a *D-Link DSL-2750B* gateway provided by Verizon, running firmware version 5.4.12.1.44.2.1.

Every few hours (at least once or twice a day, but not at any regular interval that I've noticed), all devices on the wi-fi (any OS anywhere in the house) will show a "No internet" error for the network and time out when connecting to any websites. Cycling the power on the gateway fixes the issue immediately, though temporarily. I have not been able to artificially reproduce the issue, it just happens at seemingly random intervals.

I have noticed:

- **All of the lights on the gateway box are green.** More specifically, those that are normally green (power, WLAN, DSL, Internet) are green as usual. The lights that are normally off are all off.
- **All devices can "see" the network.** It shows up in the list of available networks, but shows a message "No internet."
- **DHCP is working just fine.** The Verizon Management Console lists about 80 devices with assigned IP addresses, and the DHCP is set to assign addresses in the range of 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254.

  - The last time this issue happened, I rebooted my laptop, ran `ipconfig`, and noticed that I had received a DHCP lease for 7 days just 2 minutes prior to the current system time. So, DHCP does not appear to be the issue.
- **I can't connect to the Verizon Management Console** (default gateway, 192.168.1.1) while this problem is happening.

I have tried:

- **Updating the wireless settings.** I changed the 802.11 mode from 802.11b/g/n to 802.11n, made sure the FCC channel was set to "automatic," and changed the channel width to 40 MHz. About 5 hours later, the problem happened again.
- **Tweaking the antennae.** I tried adjusting the angle on the antennae, and it didn't seem to have any effect.
- **Eliminating potential interference.** I made sure there were no cables or electronics near the gateway box, which is sitting on an end table in the living room. That did not seem to help.
- **Checking for interference from other wifi networks.** We live in a rural area (hence DSL) and there are no immediate neighbors.

  - There are only 4 wifi networks discoverable from my laptop: the DSL network in question, our hotspot downstairs (which we set up to cover gaps in coverage from the DSL), and the two printers' networks.
  - Presently (after I cycled the power to the gateway and the internet access started working again), running `netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid` shows that the DSL network in question and one printer are both operating on channel 11, and the hotspot and another printer are operating on channel 1. Everything is working fine in this state.
- **Cycling the power.** Just to reiterate, this is the only fix I've discovered. When you press the power button on the back of the gateway box, wait 30 seconds, and then press it again, you can connect to the internet again (until the problem resurfaces).

So, I'm wondering, can anyone recommend further troubleshooting steps? I'm really not sure what is causing this issue or how to reproduce it.

Should I just buy a new gateway? I fear, if that did work, it would just be an expensive and non-specific fix. It seems there should be a setting I can change or a piece of hardware I can attempt to repair.

I would appreciate any advice! I am just an IT student, so forgive my ignorance, and if there would be a better place to look for advice, please let me know (networkengineering.stackexchange.com sent me here). Thanks again.

Comment: Can you connect to one of the ethernet ports on the router while the problem is occurring to confirm that it is indeed a router problem and not a Wi-Fi/wireless problem?

Comment: Do the Verizon DSL boxes still have a section that reports the Signal to noise for the DSL? Might want to add that to the question if it does. I'm guessing these are still rented devices from them, it's not uncommon for them to fail, and it's Verizon's responsibility to replace it if it's a rented device. Also (and I'm sure you don't want to hear it) calling Verizon customer support should initiate a PSTN circuit test from the head end. Depending on the individual tech, (some do not know how to interpret the results) may be able to tell you if something is up with your local loop.

Comment: Its generally accepted in the industry that some routers ajust have lousy firmware. Sounds like this is one of them. A new router is likely the way to go. (A lot of routers can be fixed with dd-wrt or similar, but not usually DSL ones)

Comment: Scraping the bottom of the barrel, it could be that the existing router can't handle the connection tracking/ARP table size. Not sure how much it would help but are you able to temporarily reduce the number of devices connecting to it and see if it makes a difference. Also, are you able to flash other firmware versions onto the router and see if that helps?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same D-Link DSL-2750B gateway provided by Verizon, running firmware version 5.4.12.1.44.2.1, and experience exactly the same issue. Here, the "No Internet" occurs every 24 hours, so we cycle power on the unit every morning, at the same time, before beginning work (two people working at home, sharing the Internet). If we don't cycle power, wireless devices are affected first, then wired devices.

The issue does indeed seem related to how many devices are simultaneously connected to the unit at once, and how much data is transferred over a period of time. We have 5 WiFi and 4 Ethernet connections working at once and that gets us 24 hours with pretty heavy usage. I find that when I perform a factory reset on the unit and afterward only have 2 WiFi and 2 Ethernet connections with light usage (simple web browsing, no sustained downloads of large files for several hours, or video streaming), the unit can go over 48 hours before a power cycle is required.

We have the maximum DSL service available for our area, 3.4 Mbps down / 0.9 Mbps up.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Super User! Please don't provide a solution unless it is able to solve the problem mentioned.